# probabilities of arrival time

Tags: probability

John and Mary arrive under the clock tower independently. Let X be John's arrival time and let Y be Mary's arrival time. If John arrives first and Mary is not there then he will leave. If Mary arrives first then she will wait up to one hour before leaving. John's arrival time, X, is exponentially distributed with mean of 1. Mary's arrival time has density $f(y) = {2y\over 9}$, $0≤y≤3$. Calculate the probability they will meet.

**What I've tried.**

I figured this problem should be the summation of two probabilities. The probability that Mary arrives before John + The probability that John arrives within an hour of Mary.

the joint distribution is $f(x,y) = {2y\over 9}e^{-x}$, therefore the first probability could be written as $P[X>Y]$ of the joint distribution.

$$\int_0^3 \int_0^y f(x,y) dxdy$$

this gives the answer of .822, which is well above the answer given in the book of .1125, without the second probability even being found.

I'm not even sure how to set up the limits for the second probability.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're close. You need not the sum of the probabilities, but the probability of the co-occurrence of the events required for a meeting, i.e. $P(Y \lt X \lt Y+1)$. Try calculating that probability.

Comment: that worked. that you very much

Comment: If you've got the answer, it would be useful for you to post at least a summary of your solution as an answer, so that the question does not remain technically unanswered (for the benefit of other readers).

Comment: In R, `m = 10^6;  x = rexp(m);`  `y = 3*rbeta(m, 2, 1);`
     `mean((y < x) & (x < y + 1))` returns
     `0.112467` This simulation (accurate to 2+ places) depends on recognizing that $Y \sim 3Beta(2,1)$ and uses @Chester's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that Mary arrives first, and within an hour of John can be calculated as follows.

$$P[Y<X<Y+1] = \int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{y} \frac{2ye^{-x}}{9} = .822$$